# How to remove multiple tr simultaneously in jQuery without using for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can do this, simply doing it in for loop, but I need to do it without using loop.

Is there any way to make it possible?
Below I am writing some of my code:

```js
function submitFormArchive(Status) {
    var siteUrl = $("#pageurl").val();
    $("#archive-loader").show();
    var myCheckboxes = new Array();
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='archive[]']:checked").each(function () {
        myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());});
   alert(myCheckboxes);///this one i am getting dynamic ids
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: siteUrl + 'Appadmins/ajaxUpdateArchive',
        data: {"myCheckboxes": myCheckboxes, "status": Status},
        success: function (data) {

$("#remove-id-"+myCheckboxes).slice(myCheckboxes).remove();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

```html
  <tr class="message_box" id='remove-id-<?php echo $list->id;?>'></tr>

This one in for loop 

I am posting some part of codes.




$("#remove-id-" + myCheckboxes).slice(myCheckboxes).remove();
```

Is there any for multiple, maybe I have written wrong in this above code.

Comment: `$("some selector that gets the trs in question").remove()` - I don't know what else to tell you, because you haven't made it at all clear how you know which tr elements should be removed. (And note that jQuery does use a loop behind the scenes.)

Comment: `var cbs=$("input[type='checkbox'][name='archive[]']:checked").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    var selector=cbs.map(function (el) {
        return "#remove-id-" +el;
    }).join(',');
    $(selector).remove();`

Comment: @nnnnnn  i am getting it dynamically ,no need to worry about which tr ,i can handle that part ,please tell me how to remove all the dynamic tr??

Comment: To remove any row containing a checked checkbox you can say `$("input[type='checkbox'][name='archive[]']:checked").closest("tr").remove()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='archive[]']:checked").each(function() {

    myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
});

alert(myCheckboxes); //40,39,38 //it can be any id ,as i made it dynamic .

// construct array of IDs here
var ids = myCheckboxes.map(function(id) { return "#remove-id-" + id; });
// ["#remove-id-40", "#remove-id-39", "#remove-id-38"]

// concat all id selectors together using comma `,` 
var idSelector = ids.join(",");
// "#remove-id-40,#remove-id-39,#remove-id-38"

// remove all at once.
$(idSelector).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='archive[]']:checked").each(function() {
    $("#remove-id-" + $(this).val()).remove();
});
```